# Multicast data transfer from VirtualBox to different network interfaces

Tags: docker, networking, udp, virtualbox

VirtualBox with Linux OS (Ubuntu 20.04) is installed on the physical host (Windows OS). Docker is installed in Ubuntu, in which I run the Java application. It sends packets over the network to another computer over the udp protocol in multicast mode at the address 224.1.1.244 and port 53000. I run the container with this application through docker-compose.

```
services:    
  upload-srv:
    image: ${SERV_IMAGE_STEND}
    networks:
      - es-serv-network
    network_mode: "host"
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: es-serv-v01
    volumes:
      - /home/es-serv:/home/es-serv
    ports:
      - "5003:5003"

  upload-web:
    image: ${WEB_IMAGE}
    networks:
      - es-serv-network
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: es-serv-web-v01
    ports:
      - "7001:80"
...        
networks:
  es-serv-network:
```

I switch VirtualBox to bridge mode, select the desired interface, and by specifying network_mode, the data goes to this interface. This scheme works.

But in the future it is planned to launch several such applications (more precisely 10) and each of them should send data to its network interface in multicast mode. The question is, how can this be implemented?

So far, I have one thought for everyone to create their own virtual machine, connect it to their network interface through which the data stream will flow. Is there any way to make all these applications work in one virtual machine?

The applications are not very complex, there will be no special load on the server. But to create 10 virtual machines, each one needs to allocate memory resources. And our server is not particularly powerful. I don't even know if he'll pull that much.

Docker has a macvlan network mode. And he won't help me in any way?
If Docker was installed on the host, and not in VirtualBox, then you could hang each container on your network interface and it should work. If I understood the macvlan network mode correctly.
But when Docker is installed inside VirtualBox, I don't even know how to set the network interfaces that are located on the host.

Comment: First, your multicast group, `224.1.1.244`, is in one of the RESERVED ranges (`224.1.0.0/16`) that you are not allowed to use. You probably want to use a multicast group in the Organization-Local scope of `239.0.0.0/8`. Multicast is confined to a single bridged network unless you use multicast routing, which is very different than unicast routing. You need IGMP on the bridged network, and you need a multicast routing protocol, such as PIM, to route multicast, which, unlike unicast routing, is designed to prevent multicast from going where it has not been requested.

Comment: Did I understand correctly? Will multicast not work across two bridges? It turns out that I already have the first bridge in Docker

Comment: Multicast is confined to a single bridged network unless you have multicast routing, but you need to set up multicast routing because it is very different than unicast routing. Your host OS will not have multicast routing by default, so you will need to download something that will do that for you.